# Create USB Boot device on Linux or Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have been given a MacBook Pro 15" Core2Duo A1286 with corrupted HDD structure. I would like to reinstall MacOS X but when I try to use Disk Utility to reinstall it, it tells me I am unable to install from its recovery partition. (I was able to erase the HDD).

Internet recovery launched with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> fails to install Sierra with an error `UNTRUSTED_CERT_TITLE`.

How might I create a bootable installer on a USB flashdrive from Linux Mint or from Windows 7 or 10? Unable to find how after creating an Apple Store account, the MacVerse is totally foreign to me.

Comment: Have you tried Internet Recovery?  `Cmd-Option-R` when booting

Comment: That machine is a) too old to boot from Internet Recovery - see https://support.apple.com/HT202313 b) probably too old to boot from USB & c) doesn't support Sierra, last OS it can run is El Capitan. I think best bet might be a Lion CD, then upgrade to El Cap from there..

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are going to go the route of downloading an illegal/pirated copy of an installer there is no way of downloading Mac OS on anything but Mac OS.

There are ways to do this, though. The first would be a friend with an older Mac, preferably of the same vintage as yours and have him download a compatible installer.

Another way would be to make a Mac Genius appointment. They will help you re-install Mac OS using installers available at the Apple store.

Also if there is a Mac user group in your area, go to a meeting and ask if someone can help with an installer.